# Directive to restrict forward slash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I created a directive to not allowing spl characters (except underscore and space).
All works fine but it also allows forward slashes. What am I missing here?

Below is my directive and plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ho6kztdlYau4Zi29Afa5?p=preview

```
.directive('noSpecialChar', function() {
return {
  require: 'ngModel',
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
    modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
      if (inputValue === undefined)
        return ''

    regReplace = new RegExp('[^\\w_/\s/g]', 'ig');
      if (inputValue === undefined)
          return ''
      cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(regReplace, '');
      if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
          modelCtrl.$render();
      }
      return cleanInputValue;

    });
  }
}
});
```

Comment: Looks like there is an unescaped forward slash in your regex, after `w_`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is not built correctly, if you want to replace every thing but `\w`, `_` and , you should use this one instead: `[^\w_ ]` (escaped of course).

Replace the regex on your code with this code bellow:

```
new RegExp('[^\\w_ ]', 'gi')
```

> **Note on `\s`:** the `\s` matches not only regular space chars () but it also matches other types of empty space as well (`\r\n\t\f\v`). So, I believe you should not use it as you seem not to want other kind of white space being allowed on your input.

Check the working code bellow.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.username = '';
  })
  .directive('noSpecialChar', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
          if (inputValue === undefined)
            return ''

          regReplace = new RegExp('[^\\w_ ]', 'gi');
          if (inputValue === undefined)
            return ''
          cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(regReplace, '');
          if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
            modelCtrl.$render();
          }
          return cleanInputValue;

        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Username : <input type="text" no-special-char ng-model="username" name="userName">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed escaping the forward slash in there

```
regReplace = new RegExp('[^\\w_\/\s\/g]', 'ig');
```